# Is there an identity group element in pairing groups in Charm Crypto

Tags: python, cryptography, multiplication, charm-crypto

I need to multiply a group element with another group element which doesn't change its value. As the integer multiplication of a pairing group element will alter its value.

```
group = PairingGroup('SS512')
g= group.random(G1)
g*1 ==> some other pairing group element
g*g_identity = g # Is there any g_identity element defined in charm crypto?
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's not clear. Can you cite the relevant part from the paper or use better syntax? Why do you need an identity element? All group elements are immutable.

Comment: i am iterating group elements in a for loop. In that i need to initialize  a my group element. If i initialize it as 'integer 1' its product results in a different element. So for initialization purpose i need an identity element.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. `g * 1 == g` gives `True` for me. I use charm 0.43 in Python 3.4.2.

Comment: I am using charm 0.42, in that when you give the element name to the interpreter, it displays it as object. So thought that those are two different objects. 
     `>>> g`
    `<pairing.Element object at 0x7fb2ea6083d8>`
    `>>> g*1`
    `<pairing.Element object at 0x7fb2ea611078>`


Thanks for helping...

Comment: A new object is created, but that doesn't mean it has a different value. Use `g.__str__()` and `(g*1).__str__()` to compare the values.